# In Android Not getting values from the super class methods after passing the instance of child class through Intent

Tags: java, android

Suppose, There is two model class named Parent and Child where Parent Class is super class of Child Class.

```
Class Parent {
    private String id;

    public void setId(String id) { this.id = id; }
    public void getId() { return id; }   
}

Class Child extends Parent implements Serializable {
    private String name;

    public void setName (String name){ this.name = name; }
    public void getName (){ return name; }
}
```

Suppose there is two activities in my application Activity1 and Activity2.
In **Activity1 :**

```
Class Activity1 extends Activity {
   //Create a instance of Class B and set some values.
   Child item = new Child();
   item.setId("001");
   item.setName("Test");

   //Start the Activity2 and put the instance of Child into it.
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
   intent.putExtra("item",item);
   startActivity(intent);
}
```

In **Activity2 :**

```
Class Activity2 extends Activity {
     if (getIntent().getSerializableExtra("item") != null){
        currentItem = (Child) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("item");
        Log.d("Current Item Name:", ": " currentItem.getName());
        Log.d("Current Item Id:", ": " + currentItem.getId());
     }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Current Item Name:: 001
Current Item Id:: null
```

Can anyone help me out why i am getting "null" here ?

Comment: Make class `Parent` implement `Serializable`

Comment: Just Parent class or Parent and Child class also ?

Comment: I assume for parent class will be enough. Nevertheless, in Android ecosystem you'd better stick with implementing `Parcelable` which is much more lightweight.

Answer (score 0):

```
Class Parent  implements Serializable {
    private String id;

    public void setId(String id) { this.id = id; }
    public void getId() { return id; }   
}
```

You need to **Serialize the Parent** class also.